# Scrolling some div and same time scrolling body

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

First of all I didn't want to start trying this before asking, I am wondering how it is done to have like:

```
body{width: 100%; height: 150%; background: url('someimg.png') no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%}
div{width: 100%; margin-top: 300px; height: 100%; background: red;}//and this div contains other elements so his content became scrollable
```

Now You know some examples where while you scroll down the back is scrolling as well as front, but back is a lot slower than front in way like if i scrolled down 30% I want to body with 150% height scroll down for 30% and div with like 300% height scroll down for his 30% in same time so it looks like the background image is scrolling as well but slower.

I want to ask you which way is used for this?

```
 CSS3, JAVASCRIPT or SOMETHING ELSE? OR MIXED?
```

Comment: Google for parallax effect

Comment: Thanks, is there some list for all that effects names? I am always wordless for effects etc....

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so i think you are looking for the **parallax effect**. You can do that by manually coding it yourself using jquery or sometimes just CSS as well, but it might take a lot of time if you are just starting out, i would recommend that you use plugins like:
1. [Parallax.js](http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/)
2. [Skrollr](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/)
3. [Parallax-Scroll](http://parallax-scroll.aenism.com/)
and more... just **google parallax scroll plugins**, as some of them are quite easy to use which will save a lot of time.

Comment: Some guy already commented and I found what I needed but anyway since this answer is same as comment with little more info I will accept it.